# IE11でエレメント要素にfilter:blur効果

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

以下の要素に対してfilter:blur効果を行いたいのですが、
IE11の場合はどのように指定すれば良いのでしょうか？

HTML

```
<p class="filter-blur">フィルター</p>
```

CSS

```
.filter-blur {
    /* Default Filter */
    filter         : blur(5px);
    -webkit-filter : blur(5px);
    -moz-filter    : blur(5px);
    -o-filter      : blur(5px);
    -ms-filter     : blur(5px);

    /* IE9 */
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius=5);
}
```

画像に対してはいくつかサンプルがあったのですが、
要素に対してはありません。

できれば以下の対応は行いたくないです。
＃ 今後の更新で支障が出る可能性が高いため

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9">
```

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 実現手段がないように思います。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。やはり厳しそうですね。ぼかし系対応しているサイトを見るとどこもIE11だとぼかしがかかってないです…。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Can I use](https://caniuse.com/#search=filter)で見る限り、IE11はfilter未対応のようです。
そのため、単純な方法では実現不可能だと思います。